# For $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma^2)$, show that $\hat{\sigma}^2_0 = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu_0)^2$ is a UMVU estimate of $\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Somewhere along the way I make an error and I can't seem to find where.

I mostly use central moments in the derivation so I will state them here for the sake of  completeness: for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$,
$$
\mathbb{E}(X - \mu)^2 = \sigma^2, \quad \mathbb{E}(X - \mu)^4 = 3\sigma^4, \quad \mathbb{V}(X - \mu)^2 = \mathbb{E}(X - \mu)^4 - (\mathbb{E}(X - \mu)^2)^2 = 3\sigma^4 - \sigma^4 = 2\sigma^4.
$$

Firstly, it's easy to show that the estimator $\hat{\sigma}^2_0(\mathbf{X})$ is unbiased. Therefore, the information inequality (or equality for uniform minimum variance unbiasedness) takes the form
$$
\mathbb{V}(\hat{\sigma}^2_0(\mathbf{X})) \geq \frac{1}{n I_1(\theta)}.
$$
where $I_1(\theta)$ is the Fisher information number. Lets derive $I_1(\theta)$ first
\begin{align}
I_1(\theta) = \mathbb{E}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x, \theta))^2 & = \mathbb{E}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x - \mu)^2 - \log(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma ))^2, \\
& = \mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{\sigma^3}(x-\mu)^2 - \frac{1}{\sigma})^2, \\
& = \mathbb{E}(\frac{(x-\mu)^2 - \sigma^2}{\sigma^3})^2, \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}(x-\mu)^4 - 2 \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}(x-\mu)^2 + \sigma^4}{\sigma^6}, \\
& = \frac{3\sigma^4 - 2\sigma^4 + \sigma^4}{\sigma^6}, \\
& = \frac{2}{\sigma^2}.
\end{align}
Now for the variance of the estimator,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(\hat{\sigma}^2_0(\mathbf{X})) & = \mathbb{V}(n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu_0)^2) \\
& = n^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{V}(X_i - \mu_0)^2 \\
& = n^{-2} n 2 \sigma^4 \\
& = n^{-1} 2\sigma^4.
\end{align}
Now the inequality takes the form
$$
\frac{2\sigma^4}{n} \geq \frac{\sigma^2}{2n}
$$
So what is missing is a square value of $\sigma$ and a factor of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to estiamte $\sigma^2$, so in the definition of Fisher information, you should take derivative with resepct to $\sigma^2$ and not $\sigma$ which you currently seem to be doing.